# Como posso fazer um gráfico de barras horizontais duplas em Python a partir de um arquivo .xlsx?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, table, plot

Estou tentando ler o .xlsx e formar um gráfico a partir do arquivo por meio do Python.

[Esse é o arquivo e a forma que consegui exibir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S2xu.png)

[Gostaria que ficasse dessa forma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFVI.png)

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow?cb=1

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Primeiramente certifique-se que o arquivo esta em .xlsx e não .lsx! Considerando que o arquivo realmente esta em .xlsx você deve importar a biblioteca "openpyxl" para abrir o arquivo, tbm vou usar a biblioteca pandas, plotly para criar o gráfico e a OS para interagir com o OS, vai ficar assim mais ou menos:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import openpyxl
import os

# DEFINIR Caminho completo do arquivo
diretorio = r'C:\Users\Área de Trabalho\Arquivo'
nome_arquivo = 'arquivo.xlsx'
caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(diretorio, nome_arquivo)

# Abrir aquivo
arquivo_excel = openpyxl.load_workbook(caminho_arquivo)

# Selecion planilha
planilha = arquivo_excel.active

# Crie DataFrame com os dados
df = pd.DataFrame(planilha.values)

# Escolha as colunas que serão usadas
coluna1 = df.iloc[:, 0]
coluna2 = df.iloc[:, 1]

# Aqui eu estou usando a Plotly mas vc pode usar outra biblioteca grafica para plotar o grafico
Linhas01 = go.Bar(
    y=coluna1,
    x=coluna2,
    name='Grupo 1',
    orientation='h'
)

Linha02 = go.Bar(
    y=coluna1,
    x=-1*coluna2,
    name='Grupo 2',
    orientation='h'
)

layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group',
    bargap=0.15,
    bargroupgap=0.1,
    xaxis=dict(
        tickvals=[-10, -5, 0, 5, 10],
        ticktext=[10, 5, 0, 5, 10]
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[Linhas01, Linha02], layout=layout)

fig.show()
```